# How to run swf object in an android device using a sencha application

Tags: android, extjs, sencha-touch, flash

I am trying to run a sencha application in an Android device( tried in Android 2.3 and 4.2) that has a swf object embedded in an HTML file. The swf object doesnt appear in the device while the rest of the HTML content appears.

I have also installed Flash Player from [here](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html). But still the swf object doesnt appear on the device. Spent a day working on it but its not going anywhere. Help?

Comment: The best answer i could get till now is that it wont be possible to run swf animation in Android , at least on newer versions, for which there is no flash player available, even in the Adobe archives. But will have to find out more about this.